# Creating Custom Windows

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

I would like to create Pop-Up Windows like these but don't know which language to use to create them.

[image]

Can someone tell me which language I can use OR a tutorial where I can learn more about such custom Windows? Thank you.

Comment: Obligatory jQueryUI Dialog link; http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form

Comment: If you're not even sure which language to use, you should probably start with the basics and learn about programming on the web as a whole.

Comment: this can be done with jquery ui as AlexK said, this is how it must be http://jsfiddle.net/TPE5y/4/ , it's not working on the fiddle , this is just to give you an idea

Comment: @fatiDev, [I've fixed your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TPE5y/5/).